# Navigation Drawer not working properly - Always fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am trying to implement the Navigation Drawer into my Material Design influenced app (Appcompat v21).

Therefore I've just created the basic xml file:

[image]

You might zoom in a bit to be able to tell what I've done there:

1. Root View is the android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout itself
2. First child is the main content, here as a simple LinearLayout
3. The second child - the drawer itself - is a simple listview, 240dp wide.

As You might see, the background should be pink, because I told the main content view to be so. The listview should be blue. Now as You can see on the right in the preview window, the entire screen turns blue instead of just the listView.

Where's my issue? I told the listview to only be 240dp wide, not to match the parent.
If I try running the application, the drawer is never "closed" which means the list is just on top of the main content view.

It doesn't seem like the program knows what a DrawerLayout is and just draws it's content on the main content layout.

I can't figure out why it won't work this time.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**:
TestActivity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.test_drawer_layout);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_left_drawer);

}
}
```

Comment: you have the same thing when you use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout?

Comment: Just tested it: Yes I've got the same issue using a FrameLayout. Maybe it's worth mentioning that I disabled the 'windowActionBar' in the theme because I am using a Toolbar. But I think this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: can you post the activity code?

Comment: Edited my post. nothing special with the activity code, just initializing both objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view that is to be shown inside the drawer (in this case, the `ListView`) must have the `android:layout_gravity="start"` attribute set.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html):

> Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the
>   `android:layout_gravity` attribute on child views corresponding to which
>   side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: left or right.
>   (Or start/end on platform versions that support layout direction.)
>
> To use a `DrawerLayout`, position your primary content view as the first
>   child with a width and height of `match_parent`. **Add drawers as child
>   views after the main content view and set the `layout_gravity`
>   appropriately.** Drawers commonly use `match_parent` for height with a
>   fixed width.

Comment: Thanks, going to check that. How could i oversee that ... thanks!